# Separate Profiles for Users

Tags: users, profiles, profiling

I may be using the word - 'Profile' wrong here, but after two hours of googling am left with zero results. So, the query is as follows -

We wanted to make a site where we can invite writers to write their post and be able to edit and post easily. We achieved that using combination of plugin and custom code. We went ahead and made a `/profile` page where the current logged-in user can see his posts, his details (username, email etc) and can view/edit his articles on front end.

Now the issue is - We want to give every registered user his own such profile which any other user can visit, read his 'about me' section, view his posts etc. In short, we want every user to have their own profile, something as `/profile/userA`

Do you have any approach that you can suggest or any tutorial you can refer?

Comment: You need to create an author.php template page

Comment: @PieterGoosen But `author.php` will be same for everyone like `/profile` is right now. I believe, I'd need something like `author-{nicename}.php` and the problem is that the `{nicename}` should dynamically generate so that the code we are using in `/profile` can be used to display set of information of user.

Comment: If you click on a post author name, the user will be taken to a page which will display the author's post and info. Correct? This template will be author.php

Comment: @PieterGoosen is right. Each author on WordPress has and archive page with a URL like `yoursite.com/author/name/`. You can work directly in `author.php` instead of working in a page template and you will have what you describe in the question.

Comment: Yes @PieterGoosen was absolutley correct. After further digging I found out that `author.php` was the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @PieterGoosen in the comments, all I had to do was shift my code to a custom `author.php` and the rest was solved.